# Javascript json query in same subnet not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My problem:
I have a PLC, a Raspberry Pi with a weather station and a Solar inverter in my home network. The Raspberry and the inverter have the possibility to deliever JSON data output. I like to access these data with a HTML webpage which is placed on the webserver of the PLC.
But unfortunately I'm not able to access the JSON data within my network. Its possible to parse the data when I copy the data locally (on webserver or PC for testing purposes), so the JSON data is free of errors. But when I want to access the data directly with JavaScript, nothing happens... I tried JQuery, Ajax and also a lot of the tips regarding cross domain access.
Any tips what I can try to access the data within my network? Maybe someone with a similar hardware setup can help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You say nothing happens. That seems unlikely. If you open the javascript console in Chrome and go to the network tab what do you see when you ajax request is made?

Comment: use your localhost server as proxy to get the file contents of the json and return that via ajax

Comment: Sorry for late response, i was quite busy the last week. :-/   @bhspencer: THX for the hint with the javascript console, it didn't knew this. Due to this I know now, that when a request with JSONP is started, the inverter sends the data back. But then there is an error message, because the data is JSON and not JSONP.

Comment: @charlietfl: Thats maybe a solution, but I dont know if my webserver is able to act as proxy, because the "server" is just a feature of my PLC and not a "real" server...

Comment: can use third party service like Yahoo YQL then